# Select records that do not appear as a pair in a pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

take for example that I have an *instructors*, *subjects*, and *instructor_subject* table.

```
instructors
-----------
1
2

subjects
--------
1
2
3

instructor_subject
--------------------------
instructor_id | subject_id
1             | 1
1             | 2
```

Notice that instructor 1 has 2 subjects. Now how do I go about selecting from the pivot table the subjects that instructor 1 doesn't have (i.e instructor 1 and subject 3). While also being able to retrieve other columns from instructors table and subjects table. The other columns being the instructor name, subject name and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross join` to get all the combinations of `instructors` and `subjects` and then filter out the ones that don't match:

```
select i.*, s.*
from instructors i cross join
     subjects s left join
     instructor_subject si
     on si.instructor_id = i.instructor_id and si.subject_id = s.subject_id
where si.instructor_id is null;
```